# Can I force a maven dependency A to use a specific version of a dependency B, whilst using a different version of dependency B along-side it?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, diamond-problem

I have two maven projects, lets call them `master` and `aux`. `Master` has a dependence on `aux`, and also on a specific version of `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient`. `Aux` has a dependence on a later version of `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient`.

e.g.

```
<project...>
  <artifactId>master</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.my-company</groupId>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>earlier version</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<uses later version of http client>-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.my-company</groupId>
      <artifactId>aux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

However, `aux` depends on classes only found in the newer version of `httpclient`, and `master`'s dependencies on `httpclient` aren't forwards compatible, so whichever version I exclude, REST calls fail in the expected places.

Is there a way to require `aux` to use the newer dependency, and `master` to use the older one?

I know that I can reconcile `aux` and `master` by patching them to be able to use the same dependency, but this would be far from ideal.

Comment: Short answer: No. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381533/maven-multiple-version-of-same-dependency

Comment: You have to make a new version of aux which uses the newer version of http otherwise you are lost...

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple versions of the same library/classes on the classpath at the same time. You would have to separate 'master' and 'aux' into separate jars, embedding the needed version of `httpclient`, and load each jar with its own classloader.

There is a framework called OSGi that does exactly this. It could be overkill for you application, but if you'd like to get started you could take a look at [OSGi enRoute](https://enroute.osgi.org/).

Comment: OSGi is definitely simpler than trying to manage your own class loader graph!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom classloader to load specified version of class, because the default classloader will just pick the first one on the classpath it can find.