# Maven dependencies with different versions of the same sub-dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have this scenario with my Maven dependencies:

- X1 needs D2.2.
- Y1 needs Z1 which needs D2.1.

If I force everyone to use D2.2, then Z1 fails at runtime because it needs a version of a class in D2.1 (which is no longer in D2.2).  If I force everyone to use D2.1, then X1 fails because it needs a newer version of a class, which is now in D2.2.  Upgrading Z1 to the latest version has no effect because it still uses D2.1.  The same goes for X1 and Y1.

How can I make this work?

Thanks,
Alvaro

Comment: Sounds like one or both of X1 or Z1 is broken and should be fixed--although according to semver, a class shouldn't be dropped between a 2.1 and 2.2 version bump. In this case, you'll probably have to specify the dependencies to get a useful answer.

Comment: A class wasn't dropped in 2.2.  A constructor (which had been deprecated) was converted from public to the default modifier.  So now it's no longer accessible by Z1.  Ugh.

Comment: Class, method, constructor, whatever. Public API shouldn't be removed.

Comment: What "should" happen isn't relevant in this situation. Thought I wish things that "should" happen were added as a mandatory compile-time check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include two different versions of the same dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989409/how-to-include-two-different-versions-of-the-same-dependency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just encountered the [diamond dependency problem](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/2008/04/the-dreaded-diamond-dependency-problem/). It's a real pain, and it shows up wherever there is a order-like relationship. Dependency is order-like, so is inheritance, which is the reason that [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) is not permitted in Java. It even shows up in inference, with the so-called [Nixon Diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixon_diamond) as the diamond dependency analog.

To solve this, if you have access to Z1, or if it's open source, patch it / fork it / modify it to use D2.2, then modify/fork/patch Y1 to use your patched Z1.

I recommend doing patching if you have your own private/mirrored artifact repository. Create a build job that clones the open-source version, make file modifications, build it and publish to your artifact repo. Alternatively, or in addition, make the open source change.

Good luck.