# Maven issue verifying dependency : beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to integrate this dependency within my maven project:

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

However, when I try to execute the command `mvn verify` within my project I get the error attached:

[image]

thanks for the help!

**Update**

I have included my pubsub dependency like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
    <version>1.69.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The functions offered by Beam are not suitable for my project unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is the [Diamond Dependency problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479808/maven-dependencies-with-different-versions-of-the-same-sub-dependency).

If you can use the same version of pubsub as beam you should not have this conflict. Per Maven Central, [beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform/2.11.0) depends on grpc-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 1.43.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out the point is that I had on my `pom.xml` the dependency :

```
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.66.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
```

But then how should I do if I need to work with these two dependencies on the same project?